# In Objective C: Printing floating points as it is

Tags: objective-c, ios, printing, floating-point

I want to print floats points in a simple calculator program for iOS:

if the result of calculation is 5.555123125, then print the exact 5.555123125.
if the result is 1.2, then 1.2.
if 2.555, then 2.555. Not 2.56 or not 2.555000.

No zero paddings, no throwing away, no round-up-or-down's. Just as it is.

Tried formatting with %f but I had to specify the number of digits: like %10.4f.
Tried %g but it did automatic changes according to the number of digits.

Just as it is, it is that difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSNumber * test = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.555123125];
NSLog(@"number = %@", test);
```

seems to work.

Comment: Nice. Solved. But numberWithFloat doesn't work. Maybe it has sth to do with the internal structures...

Comment: Of course, float is a binary format that occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits (about 7 decimal digits). (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers) So 5.555123125 might be truncated to 5.555123 for example

Comment: also, please remember to check the answer as the good one if it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

Single precision floating point (`float`) numbers have 32 bits, of which 8 are used for the exponent. That leaves 24 significant bits, which gives you log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>24</sup>) ≈ 7 significant decimal digits. If you need more significant digits than that, move up to double precision floating point (`double`), which gives you 64 bits with 11 for the exponent and 53 for the mantissa. A `double` therefore provides log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>53</sup>) ≈ 15 significant decimal digits.

Note that this is true in any language that provides IEEE single- and double-precision floating point types, not just Objective-C. Also, the printf-style format specifier for a `double` is `%d`, so this should work fine in Objective-C with no need for NSNumber:

```
NSLog(@"result = %d", 5.555123125);
```

Learn more about floating point arithmetic:

- [The Perils of Floating Point](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score -2):

You should try using `%lf` instead of `%f` for doubles.

Comment: `%lf` is the same as `%f` when used in `printf` (or `NSLog`): "The length modifiers and their meanings are: `l` ... has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier." (C99, §7.19.6.1)